# How to Return Database Result based on CASE statements?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have an application right now that has special user roles hardwired into the executable. It is tamper proof, but is a bit of a mess when it comes to new hires, role changes, etc.

So, I want to create a stored procedure that can return the appropriate employee badge numbers for any given operation.

My expertise is in C# development, but I am also the guy who works on the SQL Server (2000) database.

Here is what I'm starting out with, but T-SQL does not like this at all!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp1_GetApprovalBadges(@operation varchar(50)) as
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  declare @op varchar(50); 
  declare @num varchar(50); 
  declare @table table (NUM varchar(50) null);

  select @op=upper(@operation);
  case
    when @op='CLERK' then
      insert into @table (NUM) values (@num) where @num in ('000988','001508','003790','007912') end
    when @op='HRMANAGER' then
      insert into @table (NUM) values (@num) where @num in ('003035') end
    when @op='HUMANRESOURCES' then
      insert into @table (NUM) values (@num) where @num in ('002864','005491') end
    when @op='INFORMATIONTECHNOLOGY' then
      insert into @table (NUM) values (@num) where @num in ('001258','003423','007135','007546') end
    end;
    SELECT NUM from @table order by NUM;
END
GO
```

I realize this is very much like code that I write and is not database related, but having the database there affords me a great way to store and execute some scripts that I can modify as needed to keep my application working.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving? How do you call this from the application? Does it run in MSSMS?

Comment: `CASE` is an EXPRESSION that returns a single value. You can't use it for control-of-flow logic like you're attempting. Also, your insert syntax is quite incorrect. Where are these values for @num supposed to be coming from?

Comment: The error is simply `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.` for every line. I'm sure there is a better way, but this would be the fastest way for me to get something up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least two issues

1. Replace case with if elses
2. execute table variables using dynamic sql

for example

```
if @op='CLERK'
  begin
      exec 'insert into ' + @table + '(NUM) values (' + @num + ') where' + @num + 'in    (''000988'',''001508',''003790',''007912'')' 
  end
  else if @op='HRMANAGER'
  begin
      i-- see above
  end
  else if @op='HUMANRESOURCES'
  begin
    -- see above
  end
  else if @op='INFORMATIONTECHNOLOGY'
  begin
      -- see above
  end

  exec 'SELECT NUM from' + @table + 'order by NUM;'
```

Syntax may not be exact, but the idea will work

Comment: ? `@table` is a table variable, not a string representing a table name.

Comment: Looks like what I want to do. Management Studio says **Incorrect syntax near 'insert into '.**

Comment: If that looks like what you want to do, then you need to explain that in the question better, because it doesn't *sound* like that you've explained or *look* like the sample code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is an EXPRESSION that returns a single value. You can't use it for control-of-flow logic like you're attempting. Based on the conditions (hard-coded sets of strings) you probably meant something like this (quietly glazing over several other problems with the syntax you've attempted):

```
  ... 

  SELECT @op=upper(@operation);

  IF @op = 'CLERK'
  BEGIN
      INSERT @table (NUM) 
        SELECT '000988'
        UNION ALL SELECT '001508'
        UNION ALL SELECT '003790'
        UNION ALL SELECT '007912';
  END

  IF @op = 'HRMANAGER'
  BEGIN
      INSERT @table (NUM) 
        SELECT '003035';
  END

  IF @op = 'HUMANRESOURCES'
  BEGIN
      INSERT @table (NUM) 
        SELECT '002864'
        UNION ALL SELECT '005491';
  END

  IF @op = 'INFORMATIONTECHNOLOGY'
  BEGIN
       INSERT @table (NUM) 
         SELECT '001258'
         UNION ALL SELECT '003423'
         UNION ALL SELECT '007135'
         UNION ALL SELECT '007546'
  END

  SELECT NUM from @table order by NUM;

  ...
```

Comment: Why is it the way to do **SQL** is NOT what looks efficient to a C# guy?

Comment: @jp2code Because SQL is not OOP? Do you think SQL folks find iteration efficient?

Comment: **[Touche!]** Basically, this is the only way to `INSERT` multiple items at a time, though?

Comment: @jp2code in SQL Server 2000? Yes, this is the technique I always used when I was using software that is 13+ years old. Any reason a C# guy concerned with performance is using SQL Server 2000? :-)

Comment: Because my employer is too cheap to upgrade! FYI, I'll probably delete this post. I have since searched using the phrase *multiple inserts*, found many hits, and several on here that were closed as "too localized."